# jquery adding data to a div dynamically

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="sample">
</div>
```

I would like to add data to the sample div on click.
I am able to get the data to this function. verified with alert
but it is not appending to the sample div.

```
$("#editsubmit").click(function(){

                  var val = $('[name=name111]').val();
                    var newHTML = '<input type="checkbox" name="'+val+'<br>';
                    $("#sample").append( newHTML );

           });
```

Comment: # is used for id but `sample` in your case is a class. So use dot(".sample") instead.

Answer (score 6):

`Class` and `id` attributes mismatch.you have given as class and selecting as `ID`

```
 $(".sample").append( newHTML );
```

or change your div to

```
<div id="sample">  and then  $("#sample").append( newHTML );
```

Answer (score 2):

sample is not id in your code its a class so change it to .sample instead of #sample.

Answer (score 1):

You used

```
 $("#sample").append( newHTML );
```

but you defined sample to be a class (not an id) so you should use

```
     $(".sample").append(newHTML);
```

To summarize, the "." is used for class and the "#" is used for id.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#sample")
```

is used for id

```
$(".sample")
```

is used for class